# Error when debugging an Azure function on Visual Studio Code ('LogType' was not present)

Tags: python, azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I am using Python 3.7.3 on Visual Studio Code.

Debugging locally a very simple Azure function with a BlobTrigger throws an error

```
An unhandled exception has occurred. Host is shutting down.
System.Private.CoreLib: The given key 'LogType' was not present in the dictionary.
```

The function is just the default given by VS Code when setting up the function using BlobTrigger (see below)

```py
import logging

import azure.functions as func


def main(myblob: func.InputStream):
    logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob \n"
                 f"Name: {myblob.name}\n"
                 f"Blob Size: {myblob.length} bytes")
```

The output of the terminal is the following:

```
> Executing task: venv\Scripts\python -m pip install -r requirements.txt <

Requirement already satisfied: azure-functions==1.0.5 in d:\epiq\code\functions\blob_trigger_add\venv\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (1.0.5)

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

> Executing task: venv\Scripts\activate ; func host start <

Found Python version 3.7.3 (python).

                  %%%%%%   
                 %%%%%%    
            @   %%%%%%    @
          @@   %%%%%%      @@    
       @@@    %%%%%%%%%%%    @@@ 
     @@      %%%%%%%%%%        @@
       @@         %%%%       @@
         @@      %%%       @@
           @@    %%      @@
                %%
                %

Azure Functions Core Tools (2.7.1948 Commit hash: 29a0626ded3ae99c4111f66763f27bb9fb564103)
Function Runtime Version: 2.0.12888.0
[29/11/2019 20:09:00] File 'C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\dotnet.exe' is not found, 'dotnet' invocation will rely on the PATH environment variable.
[29/11/2019 20:09:00] Building host: startup suppressed: 'False', configuration suppressed: 'False', startup operation id: '73e149e8-6e47-438e-84b1-d6726b330145'
[29/11/2019 20:09:00] Reading host configuration file 'D:\Epiq\Code\functions\blob_trigger_add\host.json'
[29/11/2019 20:09:00] Host configuration file read:
[29/11/2019 20:09:00] {
[29/11/2019 20:09:00]   "version": "2.0",
[29/11/2019 20:09:00]   "extensionBundle": {
[29/11/2019 20:09:00]     "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
[29/11/2019 20:09:00]     "version": "[1.*, 2.0.0)"
[29/11/2019 20:09:00]   }
[29/11/2019 20:09:00] }
[29/11/2019 20:09:00] Looking for extension bundle Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle at C:\Users\zorzi\AppData\Local\Temp\Functions\ExtensionBundles\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle
[29/11/2019 20:09:00] Found a matching extension bundle at C:\Users\zorzi\AppData\Local\Temp\Functions\ExtensionBundles\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle\1.1.1
[29/11/2019 20:09:00] Fetching information on versions of extension bundle Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle available on https://functionscdn.azureedge.net/public/ExtensionBundles/Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle/index.json
[29/11/2019 20:09:00] Skipping bundle download since it already exists at path C:\Users\zorzi\AppData\Local\Temp\Functions\ExtensionBundles\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle\1.1.1
[29/11/2019 20:09:00] Loading Extention bundle from C:\Users\zorzi\AppData\Local\Temp\Functions\ExtensionBundles\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle\1.1.1
[29/11/2019 20:09:00] Reading functions metadata
[29/11/2019 20:09:00] 1 functions found
[29/11/2019 20:09:00] Loading startup extension 'AzureStorage'
[29/11/2019 20:09:00] Loaded extension 'AzureStorage' (3.0.10.0)
[29/11/2019 20:09:00] File 'C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\dotnet.exe' is not found, 'dotnet' invocation will rely on the PATH environment variable.
[29/11/2019 20:09:00] Initializing Warmup Extension.
[29/11/2019 20:09:00] Initializing Host. OperationId: '73e149e8-6e47-438e-84b1-d6726b330145'.
[29/11/2019 20:09:00] Host initialization: ConsecutiveErrors=0, StartupCount=1, OperationId=73e149e8-6e47-438e-84b1-d6726b330145
[29/11/2019 20:09:00] LoggerFilterOptions
[29/11/2019 20:09:00] {
[29/11/2019 20:09:00]   "MinLevel": "None",
[29/11/2019 20:09:00]   "Rules": [
[29/11/2019 20:09:00]     {
[29/11/2019 20:09:01]       "ProviderName": null,
[29/11/2019 20:09:01]       "CategoryName": null,
[29/11/2019 20:09:01]       "LogLevel": null,
[29/11/2019 20:09:01]       "Filter": "<AddFilter>b__0"
[29/11/2019 20:09:01]     },
[29/11/2019 20:09:01]     {
[29/11/2019 20:09:01]       "ProviderName": "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Diagnostics.SystemLoggerProvider",
[29/11/2019 20:09:01]       "CategoryName": null,
[29/11/2019 20:09:01]       "LogLevel": "None",
[29/11/2019 20:09:01]       "Filter": null
[29/11/2019 20:09:01]     },
[29/11/2019 20:09:01]     {
[29/11/2019 20:09:01]       "ProviderName": "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Diagnostics.SystemLoggerProvider",
[29/11/2019 20:09:01]       "CategoryName": null,
[29/11/2019 20:09:01]       "LogLevel": null,
[29/11/2019 20:09:01]       "Filter": "<AddFilter>b__0"
[29/11/2019 20:09:01]     }
[29/11/2019 20:09:01]   ]
[29/11/2019 20:09:01] }
[29/11/2019 20:09:01] FunctionResultAggregatorOptions
[29/11/2019 20:09:01] {
[29/11/2019 20:09:01]   "BatchSize": 1000,
[29/11/2019 20:09:01]   "FlushTimeout": "00:00:30",
[29/11/2019 20:09:01]   "IsEnabled": true
[29/11/2019 20:09:01] }
[29/11/2019 20:09:01] SingletonOptions
[29/11/2019 20:09:01] {
[29/11/2019 20:09:01]   "LockPeriod": "00:00:15",
[29/11/2019 20:09:01]   "ListenerLockPeriod": "00:00:15",
[29/11/2019 20:09:01]   "LockAcquisitionTimeout": "10675199.02:48:05.4775807",
[29/11/2019 20:09:01]   "LockAcquisitionPollingInterval": "00:00:05",
[29/11/2019 20:09:01]   "ListenerLockRecoveryPollingInterval": "00:01:00"
[29/11/2019 20:09:01] }
[29/11/2019 20:09:01] QueuesOptions
[29/11/2019 20:09:01] {
[29/11/2019 20:09:01]   "BatchSize": 16,
[29/11/2019 20:09:01]   "NewBatchThreshold": 8,
[29/11/2019 20:09:01]   "MaxPollingInterval": "00:00:02",
[29/11/2019 20:09:01]   "MaxDequeueCount": 5,
[29/11/2019 20:09:01]   "VisibilityTimeout": "00:00:00"
[29/11/2019 20:09:01] }
[29/11/2019 20:09:01] BlobsOptions
[29/11/2019 20:09:01] {
[29/11/2019 20:09:01]   "CentralizedPoisonQueue": false
[29/11/2019 20:09:01] }
[29/11/2019 20:09:01] HttpOptions
[29/11/2019 20:09:01] {
[29/11/2019 20:09:01]   "DynamicThrottlesEnabled": false,
[29/11/2019 20:09:01]   "MaxConcurrentRequests": -1,
[29/11/2019 20:09:01]   "MaxOutstandingRequests": -1,
[29/11/2019 20:09:01]   "RoutePrefix": "api"
[29/11/2019 20:09:01] }
[29/11/2019 20:09:01] Starting JobHost
[29/11/2019 20:09:01] Starting Host (HostId=gz-1173307470, InstanceId=09d46616-c233-4dd9-930f-22b04ad79087, Version=2.0.12888.0, ProcessId=6164, AppDomainId=1, InDebugMode=False, InDiagnosticMode=False, FunctionsExtensionVersion=(null))
[29/11/2019 20:09:01] Loading functions metadata
[29/11/2019 20:09:01] 1 functions loaded
[29/11/2019 20:09:01] Loading proxies metadata
[29/11/2019 20:09:01] Initializing Azure Function proxies
[29/11/2019 20:09:01] 0 proxies loaded
[29/11/2019 20:09:01] Starting worker process:python  c:/Users/zorzi/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.11.50794/pythonFiles/ptvsd_launcher.py --default --host 127.0.0.1 --port 9091 --wait "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\azure-functions-core-tools\tools\workers\python\3.7/WINDOWS/X64/worker.py" --host 127.0.0.1 --port 51997 --workerId 5649816b-40f6-45bd-99f3-3c2206db4644 --requestId 7c027cc0-3291-446f-9bb3-b6fafdd06bf0 --grpcMaxMessageLength 134217728
[29/11/2019 20:09:01] python process with Id=13884 started
[29/11/2019 20:09:01] Generating 1 job function(s)
[29/11/2019 20:09:01] Found the following functions:
[29/11/2019 20:09:01] Host.Functions.BlobTrigger
[29/11/2019 20:09:01]
[29/11/2019 20:09:01] Initializing function HTTP routes
[29/11/2019 20:09:01] No HTTP routes mapped
[29/11/2019 20:09:01]
[29/11/2019 20:09:01] Host initialized (760ms)
[29/11/2019 20:09:01] Host started (821ms)
[29/11/2019 20:09:01] Job host started
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: D:\Epiq\Code\functions\blob_trigger_add
Now listening on: http://0.0.0.0:7071
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
[29/11/2019 20:09:02] An unhandled exception has occurred. Host is shutting down.
[29/11/2019 20:09:02] System.Private.CoreLib: The given key 'LogType' was not present in the dictionary.
[29/11/2019 20:09:02] Stopping host...
[29/11/2019 20:09:02] Stopping JobHost
[29/11/2019 20:09:02] Job host stopped
[29/11/2019 20:09:02] Host shutdown completed.
Application is shutting down...

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

Any idea on how to solve the issue?

Comment: It will be easier for us to help if you can provide a more complete question. Can you show us what your function code looks like, as well as any relevant Startup or dependency injection code for your function app?

Comment: Hi @JudeFisher, please see the updated question

Comment: That's a good question now. I don't have an answer for you (other than to suggest that the logger is somehow incompatible: a package or lib somewhere that hasn't been updated?) but you stand a much better chance now of getting a useful solution from someone on SO.

Answer (score 3):

Change this in the host.json file:

```
{
   "version": "2.0",
   "extensionBundle": {
     "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
     "version": "[1.*, 2.0.0)"
   }
}
```

to this:

```
{
   "version": "2.0",
}
```

It worked for me, maybe it will work for you. 
Or did you manage to solve this in another way?

Comment: It seems like this issue has been resolved  [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-azurefunctions/issues/1725#issuecomment-577188267)